# Управление CSS анимацией с помощью JS

Tags: css3, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой управления CSS анимацией с помощью JS.
Есть код:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Анимация</title>
    <style>
      #anim {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, blue, green, pink);
      }
      .left {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
      }
      .right {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function toL() {
        var src = document.getElementById('anim');
        src.classList.remove('right');
        src.classList.add('left');
        setTimeout(function() {
          src.classList.remove('left');
        },1000);
      }
      function toR() {
        var src = document.getElementById('anim');
        src.classList.remove('left');
        src.classList.add('right');
        setTimeout(function() {
          src.classList.remove('right');
        },1000);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="anim">ТЕКСТ</div>
    <div onclick="toL();">ToLeft</div>
    <div onclick="toR();">ToRight</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Тут видно, что после нажатия на нужные дивы элемент поворачивается. Это реализовано с помощью добавления/удаления нужных классов.
Но в коде есть примесь гк в виде:

```
setTimeout(function() { },1000);
```

Что, если мне нужно будет изменить длительность анимации на 5 секунд, то в таком случае придётся изменять не только CSS код, но и JS + в других частях кода могут быть другие setTimeout и setInterval, что в сумме может сказаться на производительности.

Вопрос: как можно осуществить тоже самое, но без setTimeout?

Comment: Производительность - последнее, о чем здесь нужно заботится. Первое - совместимость. Второе - коллизии.

Comment: @SilverIce, хорошо, да есть не учитывать производительность, то всё равно какой-то костыль получается.

Comment: Не. Ну почему костыль. Мне даже чем-то нравится.

Я пользуюсь для анимации фреймворками, но ваш код увидел - стало интересно, даже глянул, кто из браузеров поддерживает данную фенечку. Со временем будет очень прикольно.

setTimeout у вас нужен для того, чтобы вы могли анимацию запускать повторно. Ну то есть, если у вас элементу назначить стиль .left, то анимация проиграется только при его назначении (точнее не стиля как такового, а transition-опции).
В данном случае, ждем конца анимации, потом снимаем стиль. Думаю можно обойтись без этого, но нужно работать напрямую со стилем. Пробуйте!

Comment: Все просто! В JS подставляете нужные стили. Тогда уж извращаться можно сколь угодно - от глобальных переменных до файлов настроек, где будете вытаскивать все необходимые длительности и все такое...

Comment: Да, еще. Кроме как через таймаут тут никак не сделать. Как же еще определить когда css-класс убирать?

Comment: @SilverIce, "Думаю можно обойтись без этого, но нужно работать напрямую со стилем.", можно по подробнее?

Comment: @Антон Мухин, "Все просто! В JS подставляете нужные стили. Тогда уж извращаться можно сколь угодно", вот как раз таки извращаться хочу как можно меньше.

Comment: @Антон Мухин, "Да, еще. Кроме как через таймаут тут никак не сделать.", можно. Есть событие "transitionend", но есть минусы:
1. в браузерах оно реализовано с префиксами.
2. если очень часто нажимать на кнопки "ToLeft" и "ToRight" то это только увеличивает количество обработчиков события, которые я не знаю как можно правильно удалить..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот немного переделал.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Анимация</title>
    <style>
        #anim {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, blue, green, pink);
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var isTransitionOn = false;

        function toL() {
            if (isTransitionOn === true)
                return;

            isTransitionOn = true;

            var src = document.getElementById('anim');
            src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "all 1s";
            src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(-360deg)";

            src.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
                src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "";
                src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "";
                isTransitionOn = false;
            }, true);
        }

        function toR() {
            if (isTransitionOn === true)
                return;

            isTransitionOn = true;

            var src = document.getElementById('anim');
            src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "all 1s";
            src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(360deg)";

            setTimeout(function() {
                src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "";
                src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "";
                isTransitionOn = false;
            },1000);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="anim">ТЕКСТ</div>
<div onclick="toL();">ToLeft</div>
<div onclick="toR();">ToRight</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Тут у нас используется и событие `webkitTransitionEnd`, и таймаут. Тут уж как удобнее будет. Как видите, все числа и указание стилей находится в коде JS, который динамично подставляет и убирает нужные стили CSS.

Также я тут сделал защиту, чтобы нельзя было много раз тыкать. Это указывается в глобальном флаге `isTransitionOn`.

UPD1:

```
  elem.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', go, false);
  elem.addEventListener('mozTransitionEnd', go, false);
  elem.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', go, false);
  elem.addEventListener('msTransitionEnd', go, false);// IE 10+ вроде
```

**UPD2:**

Вот посмотрите и убедитесь что сколько бы не добавляли одну и ту же функцию, она за одно возникновение события, будет только один раз исполняться.

```
var ff = function () {
        var src = document.getElementById('anim');
        src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "";
        src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "";
        isTransitionOn = false;
        console.log("Делаем");
    };

    function toL() {
        if (isTransitionOn === true)
            return;

        isTransitionOn = true;

        var src = document.getElementById('anim');
        src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "all 1s";
        src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(-360deg)";

        src.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', ff, true);
    }
```

Comment: > Как видите, все числа и указание стилей находится в коде JS, который динамично подставляет и убирает нужные стили CSS.


Наверное, я не совсем правильно выразился. Я делаю небольшую обёртку(фреймфорк, если хотите) на CSS с примесью JS. Мне нужно, чтобы если я изменю в CSS коде время выполнения анимации, то JS это сам поймёт, т.е. чтобы не приходилось менять код на JS.

Comment: Ну вы прям хотите чтобы я полностью подумал за вас. Неужели вам не ясно как из всей полученной информации и примеров сделать то что надо?

Comment: Но опять же, в вашем варианте есть несколько нюансов.

1. При каждом клике увеличивается количество одинаковых обработчиков. Это можно проверить так: 

    src.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
       src.style['-webkit-transition'] = "";
       src.style['-webkit-transform'] = "";
       isTransitionOn = false;
       console.log('log');
    }, true);

2. Нужно рассчитывать ещё и на другие браузеры. Получается, нужно ещё в добавок проверять есть ли это свойство в браузере + это же свойство, но с префиксами.

А вот за идею с флагом спасибо, как-то сам не додумался))

Comment: @Антон Мухин,
 > Ну вы прям хотите чтобы я полностью подумал за вас.

Нет. Мне просто нужно дать идею.
Если бы я знал, как убрать обработчик события после того, как оно завершилось, то можно было бы выбрать вариан с src.addEventListener().

А вариант с setTimeout() не подходит из-за того, что там нужно точно указывать время.


Ещё есть вариант, как-то из CSS свойств узнавать время выполнения и уже его использовать, но это подойдёт только для setTimeout().

Comment: >>>> src.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
...
А чем такое не подходит? Все прекрасно работает. И еще, можно функцию "on" использовать!

Comment: Вот вам еще идея: парсите CSS и определяете какое время будет выполняться. Или навешиваете просто обработчики при помощи именно addEventListener. Судя по учебнику, если несколько раз зарегистрировать в эл-те одну и ту же ф-ю, то она выполнится только единожды! Так что можно смело определить переменную с нужной функцией и отправить в обработчик. А когда не нужна больше будет эта ф-я, удалить обработчик при помощи соответствующей функции.

Comment: @Антон Мухин, 
 > Судя по учебнику, если несколько раз зарегистрировать в эл-те одну и ту же ф-ю, то она выполнится только единожды!

Добавьте в конце обработчика: console.log('log'); 
И запустите 5 раз кручение дива на лево. По вашей логике в консоли "log" должно вывестись 5 раз, но выводится 15 => обработчики накапливаются. Или я что-то перепутал?

Comment: @LightShock Обновил ответ, посмотрите и убедитесь что ф-я выполняется всегда один только раз! Она будет 15 раз исполняться только в моем самом первом примере, когда в функцию добавления события отправляется всегда заново созданная ф-я, а не ссылка на одну и ту же ф-ю. Тут же логично! Как браузер определит где какая ф-я, если ссылки на них указывают в разные места памяти.